# NoneType' object has no attribute '__getitem__'

Tags: python, openstack, openstack-nova

I am getting the following error while trying nova-list cli command in an openstack setup.
NoneType' object has no attribute '**getitem**'

```
 DEBUG (shell:777) 'NoneType' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/opt/stack/python-novaclient/novaclient/shell.py", line 774, in main
        OpenStackComputeShell().main(map(strutils.safe_decode, sys.argv[1:]))
      File "/opt/stack/python-novaclient/novaclient/shell.py", line 685, in main
        self.cs.authenticate()
      File "/opt/stack/python-novaclient/novaclient/v1_1/client.py", line 169, in authenticate
        self.client.authenticate()
      File "/opt/stack/python-novaclient/novaclient/client.py", line 382, in authenticate
        auth_url = self._v2_auth(auth_url)
      File "/opt/stack/python-novaclient/novaclient/client.py", line 469, in _v2_auth
        return self._authenticate(url, body)
      File "/opt/stack/python-novaclient/novaclient/client.py", line 484, in _authenticate
        return self._extract_service_catalog(url, resp, respbody)
      File "/opt/stack/python-novaclient/novaclient/client.py", line 307, in _extract_service_catalog
        self.auth_token = self.service_catalog.get_token()
      File "/opt/stack/python-novaclient/novaclient/service_catalog.py", line 29, in get_token
        return self.catalog['access']['token']['id']
    TypeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
    ERROR: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '__getitem_
```

_'

What does that mean?Is there any problem with my openstack setup or it's some python related error?

Comment: Impossible to tell without more context. You need to include the *full* traceback and your code in order for people to give useful answers.

Comment: Did you provide any command-line arguments? If so, what did you enter?

Comment: yes.nova list.list is an argument here

Comment: You are accessing a null object (None), this is the python NullPointerException

Comment: `self.catalog` is `None`.

Comment: Do you have a valid keystone service catalog defined?  What do `keystone service-list` and `keystone endpoint-list` output?  Please update your question with the results.

Answer (score 7):

Literally, `'NoneType' object has no attribute...` means that you are trying to access an attribute or call a method on something that has the value `None`.

In practical terms, this means you likely have a bug somewhere that is using a variable before it is assigned a value, or using the value from a function that is returning `None`. The first step in debugging this problem is to ask yourself "why is this variable set to `None`?".

In this specific case, either `self.catalog`, `self.catalog['access']` or `self.catalog['access']['token']` is `None`.

Comment: My guess is that the this is not actually a code question.  It looks like some is trying to interpret an error from the `nova` client cli, and is probably more interested in the configuration issues behind the application error.  Arguably more of a Serverfault question than a StackOverflow question.

Answer (score 0):

### Error Message

```
TypeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

### Cause

Calling a void method in an argument list of another function call, caused the "NoneType" error for me.

### Solution

To solve, I just made the void method return the value I needed in the other function's argument list.